# Laravel Livewire Dependent Dropdown does not fill values on edit

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to implement a dependent dropdown using Laravel Livewire along with Jetstream. Everything worked fine, but there is one minor problem though. When I click on edit button, I am trying to fill the given details from the database. But unfortunately, the dropdown details do not fill. However, the text input fetches the value and displays it.

[image][image]

Here is the blade file:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <x-jet-label for="countryName">Select Country</x-jet-label>
        <select class="form-control" name="country_name" id="countryName" wire:model="countryId">
            <option value="">-- Select a country --</option>
            @foreach($countries as $country)
            <option value="{{ $country->country_id}}">{{ $country->country_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        @error('country_id') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;


        <x-jet-label for="stateName">Select State</x-jet-label>
        <select class="form-control" name="state_name" id="stateName" wire:model="stateId">
            <option value="">-- Select a state --</option>
            @if (!is_null($states))
            @foreach ($states as $state)
            <option value="{{ $state->state_id}}">{{ $state->state_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
        @error('state_id') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;


        <x-jet-label for="cityName" style="">City Name:</x-jet-label>
        <x-jet-input type="text" name="city_name" id="cityName" placeholder="Enter City Name" wire:model="city_name" />
        @error('city_name') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
    </div><br>
    <x-jet-button wire:click.prevent="update()" class="btn btn-success">Update</x-jet-button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <x-jet-danger-button wire:click.prevent="cancel()" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</x-jet-danger-button>
</form>
```

And edit function is like:

```
public function edit($city_id)
{
    $city = City::findOrFail($city_id);
    $this->city_id=$city_id;
    $this->city_name=$city->city_name;
    $this->countryId=$city->country_id;
    $this->stateId=$city->state_id;

    $this->updateMode = true;
}
```

When I select any option manually from the dropdown, it works.

I am new to laravel and am stuck here... Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.